# PHP XAMP session_status() is always 1?

Tags: php, session, xampp

session_status() keeps returning 1 (PHP_SESSION_NONE) every time I visit localhost page. I know storing variables,  session_start() and session_destroy() work because of the files in c:\xamp\tmp (defined in php.ini)

But why doesnt it register as session in code?

```
if (session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
    echo session_status();
} else{
    echo "active";
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: [Did you read the manual on `session_status()`?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php).

Comment: Unless you have `session_start` somewhere before the `if` then how would it be active?

Comment: Ohh - I did read it before, but I guess I didnt understand it :/
I was banging my head for an hour with that. Having a slow day 
Thank you. 
For some reason I thought php does it automatically when it receives phpid

Comment: You're welcome. Just glad that you went over it and figured it out :) Cheers! @bevelod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we mostly use isset for condition on session variable

```
if(isset($_SESSION['var'])){
    echo "Welcome". $_SESSION['var'];
}
```

maybe its helpfull for you :)