# session_status() returns none on reload

Tags: php, session, php-5.4

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60083271/php-xamp-session-status-is-always-1) <s>identical</s> **opposite** question and its OP code sample seems perfectly fine to me. I've also read (including PHP docs) that session can be checked with `session_status()` on PHP >= 5.4 and it should be fine to do so before calling `session_start()` to determine if it already exists.

Now, I'm using PHP 5.4.16 on a CentOS 7.10 machine and the `session_status()` always returns `1 (PHP_SESSION_NONE)` for me, only when I reload the page with this example:

```
<?php
$status = session_status();
session_start();
echo "The session status is : $status";
```

I expect it returns `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE (2)` when I reload page (and I'm not forcing-reload with cache clear). I'm using latest Chrome version, and the page is embedded inside a virtual host with HTTPS over port 8443.

I've checked the PHP version with both `php --version` and via `phpinfo()` script to discard any version conflict just in case, and they're same. Additionally, when I visit the session script page, the server creates empty files at `/var/lib/php/session` directory. I didn't change default PHP settings for session or anything.

To make it clear: the `session_status()` works fine if checked afterwards on same script execution (`The session status is : 2`), but naturally I'm not interested in that since I want to check if session exist in first place.

What could be wrong?

Comment: So u r saying when u reload ur session is lost??

Comment: **Danger**: PHP 5.4 has been unsupported and not got a security update in over half a decade. 5.4.16 is from May 2013 and [packed with vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-74/product_id-128/version_id-149817/PHP-PHP-5.4.16.html).  Upgrade it as soon as possible!

Comment: `PHP_SESSION_NONE if sessions are enabled, but none exists.` from documentation, means, to me so i could be wrong, that your configuration enabled session, therefore you don't get `0 (PHP_SESSION_DISABLED)` but your session is not started yet. So you get a `PHP_SESSION_NONE` as result.

Comment: Your fetching the status before you start the session. Why would it be anything but "none" at that point? That function gives you the current status on the current request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `session_status` will always be PHP_SESSION_NONE until you call session_start in the lifetime of the current request. It does not matter if on some previous request you "already started" a session: you need to "re-start" it, to resume a previously started session. This is done via cookies.

If your intent is to start a session only if the user already did something in the past that started a session (eg. they already logged in previously) and you want to resume a session but not start a new one, then you could simply check `if (isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']))`.

This may be beneficial if you know most of your users won't need a session, and you want to avoid cookies and the overhead involved with a session, but still be able to handle the cases when a session is needed.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. The main problem is I was assuming previous sessions are inmediately available when you reload page. I don't find the opposite obvious.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, session_status() only allow you to know if a session has been started, so if session_start() has been called in the current script.

- PHP_SESSION_DISABLED I think that this is returned if session are disabled in PHP configuration.
- PHP_SESSION_NONE is returned if the session has not been started in the current script
- PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE if a session has been started in the current script.

This post might interrest you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356373/how-to-disable-session-in-php#:~:text=You%20can%20disable%20the%20session,ini%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356373/how-to-disable-session-in-php#:%7E:text=You%20can%20disable%20the%20session,ini%20).

A way to check if a session has been started in a different script would be

```php
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['init'])) {
   echo 'first time session';
   $_SESSION['init'] = true;
}
```